# Xcode SO_ERROR when trying to access ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an app that is simply pulling JSON from a local web server and displaying the data. I pieced together some example code from a lot of different sources to make it, part of that includes the `SessionData` ObservableObject class, which contains login info and also contains a variable `isLoading` which is used to enable/disable a loading overlay. There's a lot of code so I've removed the unimportant parts, but let me know if you need to see more.

```
class SessionData : ObservableObject {
    ...
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var isLoading = false

    func login(){
        if email == "" || password == ""{
            self.alertMsg = "Please enter email and password!"
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
        }
        withAnimation{
            self.isLoading.toggle()
        }
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
            withAnimation{
                self.isLoading.toggle()
            }
            ...
        ...
}
```

You can see how the above code is toggling `isLoading`, which then affects the `LoginView` here:

```
var body: some View {
    ...
    if session.isLoading{
        LoadingView()
    }
    ...
}
```

That all works fine. However, another aspect of my code is the `UserViewer`, which is where the json is loaded. There is also class `FetchPosts`, which is used to fetch and store the actual json, which the UserViewer has access to.

```
class FetchPosts: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    @Published var session = SessionData()
    
    init(api: Bool, session: SessionData) {
        if api {
            withAnimation{
                print("loading")
                print(session.logged_in)
                //session.isLoading.toggle()
            }
            let url = URL(string: MyAPI.address)!

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
                do {
                    if let postsData = data {

                        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: postsData)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.posts = decodedData.result
                            withAnimation{
                                print("loaded")
                                print(session.logged_in)
                                //session.isLoading.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("No data")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }.resume()
        } else {
            ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this shows how the overall ContentView is setup:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var session = SessionData()
    var body: some View {
        if !session.logged_in {
            LoginView(session: session)
                .preferredColorScheme(.light)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                .animation(.default)
        } else {
            UserViewer(fetch: FetchPosts(api: true, session: session), session: session)
                .transition(AnyTransition.slide)
                .animation(.default)
        }
    }
}
```

You can see how I'm passing an instantiated `Session` object to both `UserViewer` and `FetchPosts`. The problem takes place in the FetchPosts code... if I comment the `session.isLoading.toggle()` either before the URLSession line or the one after the json is loaded, Xcode goes bananas! I debugged it for a while, and it seems like if I try and modify anything in the session object within FetchPosts (during the init function), it completely melts down. I get a ton of `[connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C11.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]` errors, and I can see on my web server that it's rapidly pinging the endpoint. Depending on where I access the session object (before vs after URLSession), the simulator either shows a blank white screen, or it shows the UserViewer screen for a split second with the json loaded, and then reloads, and keeps reloading.

Any idea what is causing this? I figure I must be misunderstanding a concept with passing objects, but I didn't know how to explain it without showing a ton of code! Thanks in advance, I know it's a long post.

Comment: Instead of using `@StateObject` use `@ObservedObject` and it looks like you have a reference to `SessionData` inside of your `FetchPosts` just reference that directly, ex `$fetchPosts.session` and make a declaration to the fetch posts object, also changing it to a `@ObservedObject` If that ends up being the solution, let me know so I can make a proper answer, I need rep lol.

Comment: Also, I believe an SO_Error is related to your connection, specifically connection refused.

Comment: Thing is, SO_Error only shows if I try and access the SessionData instance from within FetchPost's init function. Everything works if I comment out those toggle lines, so I don't think it's anything to do with the JSON connection directly. I think something is breaking and causing the connection to fail and retry. I tried switching to ObservedObject, but that didn't fix it. I don't follow what you are saying about the reference to SessionData and referencing using $fetchPosts.session.. can you elaborate?

Comment: You're creating a reference in your ContentView for `session = SessionData()` You have a separate class called `FetchPosts` which also creates a `session` so instead of directly creating a reference to a session in your contentView, create a reference only to `FetchPosts` for example `@ObservedObject var fetchPosts = FetchPosts()` then use `$fetchPosts.session` in your `LoginView(session: fetchPosts.session)` it looks like you're using separate references to your session, which is why you're not able to connect.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but the way my code works right now is that when FetchPosts is initialized, it fetches the JSON. So I don't want to instantiate FetchPosts until the user is verified and viewing the UserViewer screen.

Comment: Exactly, data binding will ensure that your view is updated properly when the data becomes available.

Comment: Wait so when I do `@Published var session = SessionData()` in `FetchPosts`, that is *also* instantiating a SessionData? **edit** Nevermind, I commented out the SessionData line in the beginning of FetchPosts so that `session` is referencing the init parameter as it should be, but the bug still happens.

Comment: You're passing it, and using it, but not setting it to the FetchPosts object `self.session = session`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230860/discussion-between-max-and-xtwistedx).